# What function(s) can create this pattern?

Tags: functions

What function(s) have the qualities described in the image?[image]

Answer (score 4):

One may try
$$
f(x):=1-e^{-ax},\quad a>0.
$$

Comment: Excellent, that is beautifully simple!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest also this

$$1 - \frac{1}{x+1}$$